# Deploy git pull as the home dir user

Tags: git, web, server

I wonder if its possible to set the server user and group for each **cloned** git repository.

For example, if the repository was in the directory:

```
/home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/
```

than the user would be *example* and the group would be *example* as well. But when I **clone** or **pull** through terminal (logged in as root), than the files will be saved as *root:root* instead of *example:example*.

What's the best way to prevent this from happening without having to **chown** every time a new file is added.

**So what should happen?**

1. Go to a directory of an other user `cd /home/example/` as you can see by typing `ls -all` is that all the files in this directory are owned by the user example and group example.
2. Go to a git repository or create one, in this example I created one at `/home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/`.
3. Execute the ls command there again and you will notice that the user and group is equal to root:root, but I don't want it to be like that it should be example:example.

A simple but manual solution would be.

```
chown -R example:example /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/
```

Only I'm searching for something more dynamic, also it has to work with all other git commands like pull because when you pull new commits from the repository to your local than it will be owned by root:root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the 'example' user using `sudo -u`. You'll want to do this in whatever hook `git pull` is running. If `git pull` isn't running any hooks, I suggest you read [this guide on deploying using git](http://gitolite.com/deploy.html).

Git tracks the executable bit of the file persmissions, and no more.

In general, you should avoid running things like this as root: there's no reason not to push as a dedicated git user (or the example user), and many reasons not to push as root.